# Test swing application

Tags: java, swing, testing

How do you test Swing applications? For the code, I have written Unit test cases and hence I am sure that it will work well (If it doesn't, then my test cases were not adequate). But how do you test for applications with UI. It might not appear well or functionality is vague or something.

In the last application I built, I tested the UI and it worked well; Only later did I tweaked a little code, hence disturbing the modal and the UI which got unnoticed and blew up with client. I know its a bit vague, but pretty sure people would have different techniques to test UI applications

Comment: Check out Jemmy: http://jemmy.java.net/

Comment: I think the most important thing to do is to ensure that you keep your UI code as thin as possible. Don't entangle UI code with the interesting stuff, which is what the vast majority of Swing code seems to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UISpec4J](http://www.uispec4j.org/) is an Open Source functional and/or unit testing library for Swing-based Java applications, built on top of JUnit and TestNG.

But you should know that unit testing on UI(Swing) is difficult.